# Python 3 automatic conditional import?

Tags: python, import, conditional-statements

Is there any nice way to import different modules based on some variable value?
My example:

I have a folder with different modules:

- module_a.py
- module_b.py

And in some other python file i want to import either module_a or module_b based on some config value:

```
if configVal == 'a':
    import module_a
elif configVal == 'b':
    import module_b
```

Is there some way to avoid using if-elifs? So somehow automatically?

like:

```
@conditionalImport(configVal)
import module_
```

Or something clever?

Comment: You can call `importlib.import_module()` programatically to automate this type of task if you are worried about this due to a big number of modules. For 2 it will be more code that what you would avoid.

Comment: Note that it is perfectly normal to use `if` to decide which module to import. Take a look at the official [`os` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/os.py) source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `__import__` builtin to be able to state the module name as a string.

In that way you can perform normal string operations on the module name:

```
module = __import__("module_{}".format(configVal))
```

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact,we often use `if else` or `try catch` statement to write Python2/3 compatible code or avoid `import errors`.This is very common.

```
if sys.version_info[0] > 2:
    xrange = range
```

Or use `try catch` to raise exception.After modules that have been **renamed**, you can just import them as the new name.

```
try:
    import mod
except ImportError:
    import somemodule as mod
```

**But it's bad practice to use an external script to make your script work.It is unusual to depend on external script to import modules in Python.**

Answer (score 0):

It's normal to use if/try,except for import

for example

```
import sys
if sys.version_info > (2, 7):
    import simplejson as json
else:
    import json
```